# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código:

```
function enlaces($X){
        $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM enlaces WHERE codigo = '$X'");
        if($a->num_rows()>=1){
            return $a->fetch_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    function paneles(){
        $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM paneles");

        if($a->num_rows()>=1){
            return $a->fetch_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    $paneles = paneles();

    if($paneles){
            //Inicio la lista Principal
            echo "<ul>";
        foreach($paneles as $item){
            //Inicio el Item de la Lista
            echo "<li>".$item['titulo'];
            $enlaces = enlaces($item['codigo']);
            //Valido si hay enlaces para el codigo
            if($enlaces){
                //Si Hay enlaces inicio la sublista del item
                echo "<ul>";
                //Recorro los enlaces retornados
                foreach($enlaces as $en){
                    //Agrego las URL
                    echo "<li>".$en['url']."</li>";
                }
                //Cierro la sub lista
                echo "</ul>";
            }else{
                //Si no hay URLs indico el mensaje
                echo "<li>Sin Enlaces para este panel</li>";
            }
            //Cierro el item principal
            echo "</li>";
        }
        //Cierro la lista Completa
        echo "</ul>";

    }else{
        //Si no hay paneles muestro el mensaje
        echo "No hay paneles que mostrar";
    }
```

Con el siguiente error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Tengo entendido que es porque This no está dentro de una clase y acá es donde me pierdo. Cuál podría ser la clase para que funcione bien el código?

Adicionalmente estoy agregando

```
db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "roor", "flix");
function enlaces($X){
    $a = $this->db->query($db, "SELECT * FROM enlaces WHERE codigo = '$X'");
```

pero no sé si así sea lo correcto.

Comment: Nada indica que estés en una `Clase`, aparte del uso de `$this`. Si no estás en una clase, entonces puedes definir tu variable de conexión fuera de todas las funciones, así: `$db=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "roor", "flix");`. Pero luego, tendrás que modificar las funciones, agregando un nuevo parámetro que será la conexión. Para `paneles` definirías la función así: `function paneles($db){`  y dentro de ella: `$a = $db->query("SELECT * FROM paneles");`  Para `enlaces`:  `function enlaces($X,$db){
        $a = $db->query("SELECT * FROM enlaces WHERE codigo = '$X'");`

Comment: ... la forma de llamar las funciones también cambiaría, pues tienes que pasar el nuevo parámetro: `$paneles = paneles($db);`  y `$enlaces = enlaces($item['codigo'],$db);`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear una clase que envuelva todo el codigo

   O
2. Pasa la variable db como parametro a las funciones

Answer (score 0):

Si desea manejar todo orientado a objetos, entonces debe crear una clase donde haga uso del $this, ya que si no se maneja dentro de un modelo, no funcionará y llamará a la variable $this y luego le muestra el error que ha compartido.

Utilizaré una conexión con clase para que luego haga las pruebas necesarias:

```
<?php
    class DriveDB {
        public $db_connect;

        function __construct($ip_host, $username, $password, $db) {
            if (!$this->db_connect = new mysqli($ip_host, $username, $password, $db))
                echo "No hay conexión";
        }

        public function enlaces($X){
            $a = $this->db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM enlaces WHERE codigo = '".$X."';");

            if($a->num_rows > 0)
                return $a->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            return false;
        }

        public function paneles(){
            $a = $this->db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM paneles;");

            if($a->num_rows > 0)
                return $a->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            return false;
        }   
    }

    $Instancia  = new DriveDB("localhost", "root", "roor", "flix");
    $paneles    = $Instancia->paneles();
?>
```

Verifica si la contraseña del usuario root es roor, no sé si se habrá confundido al escribirla o si realmente es la correcta. Para consultar la cantidad de filas que retorna la consulta, no hace falta poner paréntesis.

He escrito sólo la clase y la implementación, el código final que tiene sobre las condicionales, sólo lo tendrá que agregar abajo y tendrá que funcionar con normalidad.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu ayuda.
Estoy probando y recibo el siguiente error:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'titulo'
en esta línea: echo "<li>".$item['titulo'];
Adicional esto
Fatal error: Call to undefined function enlaces()
en esta línea $enlaces = enlaces($item['codigo']);

Comment: Por supuesto que fallará, tiene que hacer la llamada desde la instancia, así que como se ha llamado al método paneles, recuerde que ya no se nombran funciones, sino métodos. Ejemplo del llamado al método enlaces: $enlaces = $Instancia->enlaces($item['codigo']); Intente de esa manera caballero.